# How do I stop an unknown recurring program from executing on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Every half an hour or so, a console window will briefly appear on my screen and then close. This is extremely annoying, as it will steal focus from any other program or video game I run. Is there any way to find out what the executed program is? Is there some kind of "launched program history" in Windows?

I'm 90% sure it's not a scheduled task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download and run [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645). Add the following filter:

- Operation – is – `Process Create` – include

Wait for the console window to appear, then look for any suspicious events in the log.

Comment: Another useful Sysintenals tool is [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653).

Comment: Thanks. It was some kind of stupid automatic update program.